# Soil moisture index from European drought observatory

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, soil

For my current task, I am using the soil moisture index data from the [European Drought Observatory](https://edo.jrc.ec.europa.eu/edov2/php/index.php?id=1111). In the download section, the data is natively provided in the Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area projection (even if the map viewer gives the option of WGS8 coordinates). I need the data in the standard WGS84 longitude-latitude coordinates.

I have tried to use CDO but the files downloaded file from the website gives the following error.

```
cdo    remapcon (Abort): Unsupported generic coordinates (Variable: sminx)!
```

(sminx being the variable soil moisture index in the dataset).

This suggests that the grid information on the website is not properly provided. Doing `cdo griddes` on the file produces the following output.

```
Warning (cdfScanVarAttr): NetCDF: Variable not found - lambert_azimuthal_equal_area
Warning (cdfScanVarAttr): NetCDF: Variable not found - lambert_azimuthal_equal_area
Warning (cdfScanVarAttr): NetCDF: Variable not found - lambert_azimuthal_equal_area
#
# gridID 1
#
gridtype  = generic
gridsize  = 950000
xsize     = 1000
ysize     = 950
xname     = lon
xlongname = "projection_x_coordinate"
xunits    = "meters"
yname     = lat
ylongname = "projection_y_coordinate"
yunits    = "meters"
xfirst    = 2502500
xinc      = 5000
yfirst    = 5497500
yinc      = -5000
scanningMode = 64
```

Other attempts to transform (for example using pyproj described [here](https://climate-cms.org/posts/2021-11-02-pyproj-regrid.html)) result in transformed coordinates being infinities. Other similar examples on the internet have not been helpful.

How can I perform this transformation? Does someone already have experience in working with this dataset from the observatory?